# Eclipse error: Incompatible JVM, however, unable to update JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, java-8

I get the following error when I open Eclipse:

Incompatible JVM : Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.
Version 1.7 or greater is required.

My eclipse.ini file has 
`-vm /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk` 
(of course before -vmargs)

I have been trying to update to Java8 so I can get 1.8.0.jdk 
but it is not appearing at the above location, nor can I find it elsewhere.

When I run `java --version`, I get the follow output:

java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Have you tried looking `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/...` for Java 8?

Comment: Your eclipse.ini should not have such an explicit VM called out. This is an advanced config param for when the default VM resolution mechanims fails.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @Anthony Accioly **check for correct version of JDK** like :-

If `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_05 --exec javac -version` returns the correct version, then your problem is with:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK
```

With a privileged user execute:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
rm CurrentJDK
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/ CurrentJDK
```

For **more detail** on this click here [After upgrading to Java8, javac still shows 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202516/after-upgrading-to-java8-javac-still-shows-1-7)

Also check [Error launching Eclipse 4.4 “Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600860/error-launching-eclipse-4-4-version-1-6-0-65-of-the-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-thi)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ Brent Worden I didn't get *To critique or request clarification from an author* means. What u r saying to me ?

Comment: Note that this effectively coerces the Apple Java selection mechanism to use the Oracle JVM instead.  Mixing the two may turn out later to be a bad idea - Apple has been known to remove Java versions silently like when they upgraded Java 5 to Java 6 causing Eclipse projects to break like in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4340576/53897.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line (Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal), run the command

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

This will return the location of the 1.8 JDK. Incidentally, this *should* match

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

if that variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a 64-bit version of Eclipse 4.4 with OS X.

Comment: More explanation on this answer by @
Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen is found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598465/eclipse-in-os-x-uses-different-version-of-java-than-cli/